# Group records by date ranges and count them in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by, count, date-range

I was struggling with an ActiveRecord query but I can accomplish what I want. I have the following models and relationships:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :clinic
end

class Clinic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

And I need to get the Users placed orders by periods of time. Total orders placed in the **last month**, last **3 months**, last **6 months** and last **12 months** using the `created_at` attribute.

What I want to get is something like this:
[image]

- As you can see the orders in each period of time is the sum of the previous one so that in the first row the total in the `12 months` column is the sum of the previous 3 periods of time plus the left 6 months of the year.
- Users can appear as many times as they have clinics related to and the total for the corresponding columns is related to the given user clinic.
- Also I do need to **get date** of the very last placed order.

I've been trying some workarounds and the best way to get it was to get first the users list with the corresponding clinics. Then I went through each and every user and perform the following queries to get the total on each period of time:

```rb
users = User.joins(:clinics).select('user.id, clinic.name')

users.each do |user|
  month = user.orders.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Time.current.beginning_of_month, Time.current.end_of_month).count
  month_3 = user.orders.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Time.current.beginning_of_month - 2.months, Time.current.end_of_month).count
  month_6 = user.orders.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Time.current.beginning_of_month - 5.months, Time.current.end_of_month).count
  month_12 = user.orders.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Time.current.beginning_of_month - 11.months, Time.current.end_of_month).count
end
```

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it without iterating over each and every user record and perform the queries there!

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Untested but should work like the following:**

```rb
beginning_of_month = Time.current.beginning_of_month
end_of_month = Time.current.end_of_month

# Let's get first all orders count group by user + clinic
users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_beginning_of_month = Order.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', , beginning_of_month, end_of_month).group(:user_id, :clinic_id).count
users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_three_months_ago = Order.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', , beginning_of_month - 2.months, end_of_month).group(:user_id, :clinic_id).count
users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_six_months_ago = Order.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', , beginning_of_month - 5.months, end_of_month).group(:user_id, :clinic_id).count
users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_last_year = Order.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', , beginning_of_month - 11.months, end_of_month).group(:user_id, :clinic_id).count

# Now Let's get all users JOINED with clinics into memory
users = User.joins(:clinics).select('id', 'clinics.name')

data = {}

# Set data with (key == [user_id, clinic_id]) with the corresponding table columns
# All of this should be fast as all of these objects including user and clinic records are already in memory
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][0] means "id" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][1] means "clinic name" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][2] means "last order at" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][3] means "orders 1 Month" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][4] means "orders 3 Months" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][5] means "orders 6 Months" column
# data[[user_id, clinic_id]][6] means "orders 12 Months" column

users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_beginning_of_month.each do |(user_id, clinic_id), orders_count_since_beginning_of_month|
  if data[[user_id, clinic_id]].nil?
    user_in_memory = users.detect { |user| user.id == user_id }
    next unless user_in_memory # ignore if this user_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
    clinic_in_memory = user_in_memory.clinic
    next unless clinic_in_memory # ignore if this clinic_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
  end

  data[[user_id, clinic_id]] ||= []
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][0] ||= user_in_memory.id
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][1] ||= clinic_in_memory.name
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][3] = orders_count_since_beginning_of_month
end

users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_three_months_ago.each do |(user_id, clinic_id), orders_count_since_three_months_ago|
  if data[[user_id, clinic_id]].nil?
    user_in_memory = users.detect { |user| user.id == user_id }
    next unless user_in_memory # ignore if this user_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
    clinic_in_memory = user_in_memory.clinic
    next unless clinic_in_memory # ignore if this clinic_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
  end

  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][0] ||= user_in_memory.id
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][1] ||= clinic_in_memory.name
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][4] = orders_count_since_three_months_ago
end

users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_six_months_ago.each do |(user_id, clinic_id), orders_count_since_six_months_ago|
  if data[[user_id, clinic_id]].nil?
    user_in_memory = users.detect { |user| user.id == user_id }
    next unless user_in_memory # ignore if this user_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
    clinic_in_memory = user_in_memory.clinic
    next unless clinic_in_memory # ignore if this clinic_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
  end

  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][0] ||= user_in_memory.id
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][1] ||= clinic_in_memory.name
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][5] = orders_count_since_six_months_ago
end

users_per_clinic_orders_count_since_last_year.each do |(user_id, clinic_id), orders_count_since_last_year|
  if data[[user_id, clinic_id]].nil?
    user_in_memory = users.detect { |user| user.id == user_id }
    next unless user_in_memory # ignore if this user_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
    clinic_in_memory = user_in_memory.clinic
    next unless clinic_in_memory # ignore if this clinic_id is not part of `users` (joined with clinics)
  end

  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][0] ||= user_in_memory.id
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][1] ||= clinic_in_memory.name
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][6] = orders_count_since_last_year
end

# Lastly we need to get the "last order at" to be inserted into each data[[user_id, clinic_id]][2]
# this is the only unnecessarily slower part as this do a N-times more sql per find_by
# (but couldnt think of a quick solution yet to eager load the last order created_at)
# Feel free to change this if you know a faster way
data.each do |(user_id, clinic_id), columns|
  last_order = Order.order(created_at: :desc).find_by(user_id: user_id, clinic_id: clinic_id)
  data[[user_id, clinic_id]][2] = last_order.created_at
end

# sort the table by [user_id, clinic_id] and then puts and show the table
puts data.sort.map do |(user_id, clinic_id), columns]
  columns
end
# => [
#   [1, Providence, 2019-08-14T15:51:12.342Z, 2, 6, 12, 24],
#   [1, Joseph Center, 2019-08-22T16:26:29.151Z, 1, 3, 6, 12],
#   [2, Eubanks, 2019-08-22T16:26:29.151Z, 1, 4, 8, 18],
#   ...
# ]
```

Comment: if you have a big memory in your sever(s) or that the DB is not big yet, you can also do `eager_load` to get all associated records from DB, and then you perform your calculations in ruby code: `users = User.eager_load(orders: :clinic)` or you can start with orders: `orders = Order.eager_load(:user, :clinic)`